# Fastest way to sort a List by two fields, one alphabetical and the other custom?

Tags: c#, list, sorting

Let's say I have a `List<Pet>` and each Pet has a `Pet.Name` and `Pet.Type` field.

For example:

> Name: Bob Type: Fish
>
> Name: Rex Type: Dog
>
> Name: Alf Type: Dog
>
> Name: Fluffy Type: Cat
>
> Name: Apollo Type: Fish
>
> Name: Mango Type: Horse

Now I want to sort first by Name alphabetically, and second by Type (non-alpha).

The second sort (Type) is not to be alphabetical, but just specific/custom.

For example, let's say the order should always be: Fish, Horses, Dogs, Cats.

So a properly ordered list from the above data would look like this:

> Apollo, Fish
>
> Alf, Dog
>
> Bob, Fish
>
> Fluffy, Cat
>
> Mango, Horse
>
> Rex, Dog

Or to be more clear:

> A, Fish
>
> A, Horse
>
> A, Dog
>
> A, Cat
>
> B, Fish
>
> B, Horse
>
> B, Dog
>
> B, Cat
>
> C, Fish
>
> C, Horse
>
> C, Dog
>
> C, Cat

Which means sometimes Cat could appear before Dog, but only if there are Cats with an 'A' name but no Dogs with an 'A' name... get it?

So it's sorted alphabetically, but then within each letter group it is sorted in a custom fashion based on the second field.

So what would be the fastest way to sort this List in this fashion?

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I'm just wondering: by "fastest way," do you mean fastest for you to write or fastest during runtime?

Comment: @BrianSnow Runtime... though there is a point of no return here, I wouldn't like a 500 line solution for example.

Comment: Are you grouping by the first letter of the name and then sorting by type?  If the sort is pure alpha(name) followed by type, we should only sort by type if the names are the same, or did I mis-read?

Comment: @AlanT that may indeed be a better way of wording it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about:

```
string[] orderedTypes = { "Fish", "Horses", "Dogs", "Cats" };

var orderedPets = sourcePets.OrderBy(pet => pet.Name)
                            .ThenBy(pet => Array.IndexOf(orderedTypes, pet.Type));
```

Now that's not as efficient as it could be since it requires linear-searching the `orderedTypes`string array several times to perform the second-level ordering, but with only 4 pet kinds, that shouldn't be too bad.

If you're really concerned about that though (say there were several more pet-types), you can create a lookup first:

```
var orderByType = new[] { "Fish", "Horses", "Dogs", "Cats" }
                  .Select(Tuple.Create<string, int>)
                  .ToDictionary(tuple => tuple.Item1, tuple => tuple.Item2);

var orderedPets = sourcePets.OrderBy(pet => pet.Name)
                            .ThenBy(pet => orderByType[pet.Type]);
```

If you had an enum like this instead of strings:

```
 public enum AnimalType
 {
     Fish, Horses, Dogs, Cats
 }
```

Then the operation would be as simple as:

```
var orderedPets = sourcePets.OrderBy(pet => pet.Name)
                            .ThenBy(pet => pet.Type);
```

Comment: This should actually be sufficient for what I am trying to do, I'll give it a shot and be sure to come back and select this as the answer if it works out well.

Answer (score 3):

**OrderBy()** will do this with a custom comparer.

```
public class Pet {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1() {

    var pets = new List<Pet>() {
            new Pet{Name= "Bob", Type= "Fish"},
            new Pet{Name= "Rex", Type= "Dog"},
            new Pet{Name= "Alf", Type= "Dog"},
            new Pet{Name= "Fluffy", Type= "Cat"},
            new Pet{Name= "Apollo", Type= "Fish"},
            new Pet{Name= "Mango", Type= "Horse"}
    };

    var expected = new List<string>() {
            "Apollo, Fish",
            "Alf, Dog",
            "Bob, Fish",
            "Fluffy, Cat",
            "Mango, Horse",
            "Rex, Dog",
    };


    var sortedPets = pets.OrderBy(pt => pt, new PetEqualityComparer()).Select(pt => string.Format("{0}, {1}", pt.Name, pt.Type));

    Assert.IsTrue(expected.SequenceEqual(sortedPets));

}

public class PetEqualityComparer : IComparer<Pet> {

    readonly static string[] PetTypes = new [] { "Fish", "Horse", "Dog", "Cat" };

    public int Compare(Pet x, Pet y) {

        var xFirst = string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Name) ? 'A' - 1 : x.Name[0];
        var yFirst = string.IsNullOrEmpty(y.Name) ? 'A' - 1 : y.Name[0];

        if (xFirst != yFirst) {
                return xFirst.CompareTo(yFirst);
        }
        return Array.IndexOf(PetTypes,x.Type).CompareTo(Array.IndexOf(PetTypes, y.Type));                
    }

}
```

If the the Pet Type order can change, then it can be passed into the Comparer as a parameter on construction instead of being hardcoded.

HTH, 
Alan.